# Type conversion (*void[] to vector C++)

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
// TODO: -- original 
// void *buf[n];   // <== no variable length arrays in (V)C++ 
// TODO: -- C++ 
// std::vector<void*> buf(n);

for(unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
    buf[i] = tlsf_malloc(impl->tlsf, chunk_size);
bool outOfMem = false;
for(unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
    outOfMem |= (buf[i] == nullptr);
for(unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
    if(buf[i])
        tlsf_free(impl->tlsf, buf[i]);
```

where:

```
void* tlsf_malloc(tlsf_t tlsf, size_t size)
{
    control_t* control = tlsf_cast(control_t*, tlsf);
    const size_t adjust = adjust_request_size(size, ALIGN_SIZE);
    block_header_t* block = block_locate_free(control, adjust);
    return block_prepare_used(control, block, adjust);
}
```

and

```
static void* block_prepare_used(control_t* control, block_header_t* block, size_t size)
{
    void* p = 0;
    if (block)
    {
        block_trim_free(control, block, size);
        block_mark_as_used(block);
        p = block_to_ptr(block);
    }
    return p;
}
```

How can I convert *void[] to a vector type? What I tried:

```
std::vector<void*> buf(n);

for(unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
    buf.push_back(tlsf_malloc(impl->tlsf, chunk_size));
bool outOfMem = false;
for(unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
    outOfMem |= (buf[i] == nullptr);
for(unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
    if(buf[i])
        tlsf_free(impl->tlsf, buf[i]);

return outOfMem;
```

but I'm not sure what tlsf_free() leaves in memory after freeing buf[i].

Comment: You can do as Eugene suggests and you program should do the same as it did before - but if you call `tlsf_free()` I suspect that the memory pointed to by your `void*`ers should be considered off limits. Can you link to the documentation page for that call?

Comment: I just found the code I think you use. You can't use the memory after `tlsf_free` as I suspected. You also do not have to do `if(buf[i])` before you call `tlsf_free` because the first thing that function does is `if(!ptr) return;`. I also made a small [C++ wrapper](https://godbolt.org/z/c69W71) for the tlsf C functions that may come in handy. It should help making the memory juggling easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `void *buf[n];` with `std::vector<void*> buf(n);`. Everything should work. Do not use `push_back()`.